# Is there any way to add multiple checkbox over an image at different positions

Tags: android-studio, imageview

Is there any way to add multiple checkbox at different location over an image in imageview and that checkbox will stay at its relative position while zooming

Answer (score 0):

**No**. You can not add Views (CheckBox is a View element) inside Views that are not ViewGroups (ImageView is a View but not a ViewGroup). ViewGroups are Views such as LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc.

Yet, you can arrange your items (ImageView and multiple CheckBoxes) inside a RelativeLayout or FrameLayout which allow you to put Views in such a way, that they can overlap.